# Usergrid system requirements?

Tags: elasticsearch, tomcat, cassandra, usergrid

question, how much resources I need to run apache usergrid?
I mean hardware resources, RAM CPU

I want to deploy apache usergrid to be used as backed in our apps, the apps have a low traffic now, are custom projects to be used in small users groups (<10k)

I want to know the minimum requirements to know if it is viable for us, thanks.

Comment: Hi.. It would be nice to find out the answer of this question.. I had a EC2 instance with 1GB ram and 2.5 GHz CPU and it was not running at all.

Comment: yes, I was trying to implement an instance and reading it seems to need about 8gb for a basic good performance and 16> for a good performance in a real production environment, a bit expensive in hardware resources terms :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see of *usergrid*, I can think that the most hungry for resources component will be Elasticsearch, so to have a production environment that's working well, I guess you should start following ES' requirements:

- At least 8 GB of RAM
- At least 4 cores (the more cores you give Elasticsearch, the more love you get as it tends to works with a lot of threading, i.e. give more cores rather than more CPU processing power)
- Fast HDDs should perform fine

See [this article](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/hardware.html) on Elasticsearch.A last thing is that depending on your system, you can tune several settings on Elasticsearch to achieve a better throughput. (For instance see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/tune-for-indexing-speed.html)

Comment: Thanks for the info, we already have deployed it, it a bit expensive but it worth
we will have a few weeks of test and make a choice

Answer (score 1):

I have deployed latest version of Usergrid i.e. 2.1, which is working smoothly in apache-cassandra-2.1.20, apache-tomcat-7.0.85, elasticsearch-1.7.6 on single node of Cassandra on Ubuntu 16.04 with 8 GB Ram and 180 GB SSD. Hope this will help you.